# Java Desktop-App design - MVC with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, oop

I have a few design questions concerning my Java-Application. 
The software is a desktop application that uses a MySQL database to store different kind of objects (customers, employees, documents). Each employee has a collection of customers and each customer contains a number of documents. The whole structure is lazy-loaded via hibernate.

I currently use these four layers to build up my application

- model - objects containing the data e.g. customers, employees, ...
- views - a view for each action (adding a customer, creating a document, ...)
- controller - each view has its own controller, that controls one or more business objects
- business objects - encapsulate the logic for the actions on the models (adding a customer = customerBO, adding a document = documentBO, ...)

So when the user now wants to add a new document to a customer, the controller of the customer-view opens a new - let's call it - "document-window" that has its own controller. 
Since every document has to belong to a customer I pass the customer over as a parameter. But if I use this way I have to make sure that the current hibernate session is opened and the customer-object is reattached to the session to use lazy-loading.

So my question now: Is there a more elegant way to do this? Maybe via a session-class that stores the currently active customer or so? Or is there a mistake in my structure in general that I didn't see?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good use for a data transfer object, or a value object.  In short, use a read-only, non-hibernate, detached representation for the Customer in your UI code, rather than the Hibernate-created one.  This Customer object would be the minimal projection of the full-on Customer object from your back-end that your UI needs.  In reality, you probably don't need much more than a name and ID (depends on your UI, of course).

In the past, I've introduced a "service" interface that works only in terms of these value objects, or DTOs (these terms aren't *truly* interchangeable, but I'm trying to be flexible, and it's the concept that matters :-)).

When saving something done on behalf of the customer, call the service component `service#attachDocument(customer.getCustomerId())`, or whatever.  That component would interact with Hibernate to retrieve the customer and call customer.addDocument(documentId) (or whatever is appropriate to your model).

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not uncommon to do something like this:

```
DocumentService {
   public Document addDocument(int customerId) {
         Customer customer = session.getById(Customer.class, customerId);
         Document document = new Document();
         customer.getDocuments().add(document);
         session.update(customer);
         return document;
   }
}
```

So in the end reading the customer before adding the document might look like a perforamnce penalty but is the way to go if you don't want to pass the full Customer object along.

Usually I use something like a CustomerInfo object that just stores some related information like the id, the name, maybe the address etc. Usually everything that doesnt change often, is not critical if the user sees stale data. (if it is critical one often uses a notification event / messages to update related info objects).

Now you can  pass these CustomerInfo to many common service methods. If a Customer object is loaded from the database I usually update the customer info object to keep it in sync as best as I can.

There is only one rule here. Since the customer info can contain stale data (some other user have changed it, you need to verify the validity. You can introduce a @Version to it or compare the relevant properties if they have already changed. (You use optimistic logging aka a long user transaction and two or more short database transactions).

So in the end using reattach is nothing wrong.

If you have a local embedded database and the application using hibernate is the only user (single user setup), you might want to consider using a single session approach where you synchronize or pool every access to the session to avoid concurrent transactions / access to the database.

This way you ensure that there is only one Object representing each 'database object / row'. This makes it easy to assume that every object and every Info is in synchronization with the database. Only the case that the session is lost, you have to recover by reattaching all entities your application use to the new session to avoid having situation where two entity objects represent the same database row, which is not allowed in hibernate.

**Summary**

- Using attach is not wrong.
- Passing around entity instances in your application is not wrong.
- Remember: Hibernate usually issues a select to refresh the object and validate that it represent the current db state the current session / transaction sees (use @Version to reduce cost).
- You can use CustomerInfo / DocumentInfo objects to avoid passing along entity instances to reduce memory footprint and avoid reload.
- If performance is an issue you can use the id directly to create the document and after that create a DocumentInfo using the id you optained from the insert (SQL) statement. This way you dont have to reload the user or create a document object. This is only to reduce Memory footprint and increase performance but seams to be non of your concerns.

My advise, stick to the reattach as long as you dont have a memory consumption problem.